# c reading a file using fgets, strtok causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, io, segmentation-fault, fgets, strtok

Trying to read a file line by line,
a line from a file looks like this:

```
InputVector:0(1,3,4,2,40)
```

The code :

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
char buff[26];
char *token;

while(fgets(buff, 26, (FILE*)file) != NULL) {

    buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buff);
    token = strtok(buff, INV_DELIM1);
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, INV_DELIM2);
    printf("%s\n", token);

    while(token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, INV_DELIM3);
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }
}
```

My guess is that in the while loop `strtok()` didn't return `NULL` after the last number and kept going and caused segmentation fault. I tried adding `"\0"` to the end of `buff` after `fgets()` but it didn't do anything.

```
delim1: ":",
delim2: "(",
delim3: ",)"
```

the output i get is

```
InputVector:0(1,3,4,2,40)
InputVector
0
1
3
4
2
40
segfault
```

Comment: doesn't this already causes a SegFault `buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';` ?

Comment: You never check to see if `strtok()` returns a null pointer before trying to use that pointer.

Comment: In `while` loop, invert `printf` and `strtok`

Comment: `buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';` is useless.  If `buff` is already `NUL`-terminated, it does nothing.  If `buff` isn't already `NUL`-terminated, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You repeatedly have code like:

```
token = strtok(NULL, INV_DELIM2);
printf("%s\n", token);
```

If `strtok()` returns NULL, it's then passed on to `printf()`, which expects to get a pointer to a valid 0-terminated string because of the `%s` in the format argument. NULL is not a pointer to a valid 0-terminated string, and so bad things happen, manifesting as as a crash in your case.

Solution: Make sure the pointer returned by `strtok()` is not NULL before trying to use it.

Suggestion for the future: Learn how to use a **debugger** to step through code, and get used to using **valgrind** to help track down memory problems. You shouldn't have to make bad guesses about what's going on when you can use a tool to find out where the problem is and learn exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't Skimp On Buffer Size*. If your longest line can be `25` characters, then don't use `26` characters as the buffer size, instead:

```
#define MAXC 1024  /* constant for max characters in buf */
...
    char buff[MAXC] = 1024;
```

(It's up to you, `128` works as will any other value that guarantees that with any variation in input length you don't write beyond the bounds of your array. I'd rather the buffer be 1000-characters too long than 1-char too short.)

Then validate each `fgets` call by checking the length and that the last character in `buff` is the `'\n'` character, e.g.

```
    while(fgets(buff, MAXC, file) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen (buff);
        if (len == MAXC - 1 && buff[len - 1] != '\n') {
            fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
            /* handle error - generally by reading and dicarding
             * characters until '\n' or EOF encounterd and 
             * then either calling continue or break
             */
        }
```

This will insure you have a valid string before you call `strtok`.

**You Don't Need Multiple Delimiters**

Then, as mentioned in the comments, there is no need for separate delimiters. A single `delim` defined with `#define DELIM ":(,)\n"` or declared with `const char *delim = ":(,)\n"` is sufficient. Then you can simply loop over all tokens with:

```
    for (token = strtok(buff, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim))
        printf ("%s\n", token);
```

**Short Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buff[MAXC] = "";
    char *token = NULL;
    const char *delim = ":(,)\n";
    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!file) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buff, MAXC, file) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen (buff);
        if (len == MAXC - 1 && buff[len - 1] != '\n') {
            fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
            /* handle error - generally by reading and dicarding
             * characters until '\n' or EOF encounterd and 
             * then either calling continue or break
             */
        }

        for (token = strtok(buff, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim))
            printf ("%s\n", token);
    }
    if (file != stdin) fclose (file);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(you can adjust `delim` if you need a different result)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "InputVector:0(1,3,4,2,40)" | ./bin/strtok_delims
InputVector
0
1
3
4
2
40
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I like `buffer[strcspn(buffer, “\n”)] = '\0';` as it avoids the conditional in the code and works when the string is empty, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you have a good point there. Habit I guess. I generally make use of `strlen`, so my normal check is `if (len && buff[len - 1] == '\n') buff[--len] = '\0'; else if (len == MAXC - 1) { /* string too long */ }`. (which preserves the updated string length in `len` after truncating the newline) Here there was no continued use of `buff` as a full-string necessitating the removal of the newline, so I just shortened the test somewhat to check only that the line fit in `buff`.